# hibernate/jpa criteria, query if an object exists in a many to many relation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I have an class `Offer` with a many to many relation `department`:

```
class Offer {

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH })
    @JoinTable(name = "Offer_Department", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "offer_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "namecode_id"))
    private Set<NamedCode> department;

    ...
}
```

How can I use the JPA `CriteriaBuilder` to search all `Offer` objects which contain a certain `department` (`NamedCode`).

This should be part of a greater query (see the TODO part):

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = getSession().getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Offer> criteria = builder.createQuery(Offer.class);
Root<Offer> root = criteria.from(Offer.class);

List<Predicate> restrictions = new ArrayList<>();
if (fromDate != null && toDate != null) {
    restrictions.add(builder.between(root.get("entryDate"), fromDate, toDate));
}
if (department != null) {
    // TODO check if the Offer object has assigned the passed department
}
// add more restrictions

criteria.orderBy(builder.asc(root.get("entryDate")));
```

Comment: perhaps join to the Department, and then put a constraint on the Department?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, I have to use a join after all:

```
restrictions.add(builder.equal(root.join("department").get("id"), department.getId()));
```

Comment: what if I want to check if any department for the each offer exists. Let's suppose I want all offers which has a specific department and all offers without any department. @flavio.donze